# Why is the following handler identified as 404 handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm looking through `app.js` generated by express generator, and there is the following code:

```
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});
```

My question is why the last middleware function is identified as a function that is executed when `not found` error should be returned?

Is it based on the assumption that if this function is called it means that no other middleware/router function finished processing the request with `res.send()` and hence wasn't interested in the request, so probably there is no handler for the request? And if so, than this `404` handler function should always be added last, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's because it is the last one i.e. *there are no more valid routes, therefore this must be an error.*

Comment: Yes, it is exactly as you stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly as you said, as stated in http://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html

> How do I handle 404 responses? 
>   In Express, 404 responses are not the
>   result of an error, so the error-handler middleware will not capture
>   them. This behavior is because a 404 response simply indicates the
>   absence of additional work to do; in other words, Express has executed
>   all middleware functions and routes, and found that none of them
>   responded. All you need to do is add a middleware function at the very
>   bottom of the stack (below all other functions) to handle a 404
>   response:
>
> ```
> app.use(function (req, res, next) {
>     res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
> })
> ```

Comment: thanks, but some other middleware function might still write something to the response, correct?

Comment: Yes, it could write to the response and still call `next()` to go to the next handler.